Google Docs Menu and Toolbar
The font size on my Menu and Toolbar is tiny. Is there a way to increase the text font size?
I Googled for answers, but I only found how to increase the font inside the document, which I already know. I can't find a way to make it larger on the Menu and Toolbar.

This could be a chrome zoom issue. Go to the three dots at the top of your browser, click zoom, and adjust back to 100%.

Unfortunately there isn't a way to increase the font in docs it has other accesibility options[2]
In this case I rather suggest to use Chrome accesibility[2] this will enable you to increase the "page zoom" and will help you with the size of the displayed font in the menu and tool bar
[1]Docs Accesibility Features
[2]Set Page Zoom in Chrome

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Not all questions on this site should be answered. For details see [answer].
